# c# convert yyyymmdd text to dd/MM/yyyy

Tags: c#

I have some text in rows as yyyymmdd (eg: 20181211) which I need to convert to dd/MM/yyyy

I am using:

```
cashRow["BusinessDate"] = Convert.ToDateTime(row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString()).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I get the error "string was not recognized as a valid DateTime.
Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Comment: what is value in `row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString()`

Comment: string input = "20181211";
            DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(input, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Instead of using `Convert.ToDateTime` use `DateTime.tryParse` and specify the date format and then use the ToString method.

Comment: I have 20181211 in row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString()

Comment: it appears you are passing in the string date with a format of  `dd/MM/yyy` to the `Convert.ToDateTime` method ... shouldn't it be "yyyyMMdd"?

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to use `ParseExact` (or [`TryParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact?view=netframework-4.7.2)) to parse the date:

```
var date = "20181217";
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
var formattedDate = parsedDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Here we tell `ParseExact` to expect our date in yyyyMMdd format, and then we tell it to format the parsed date in dd/MM/yyyy format.

Applying it to your code:

```
cashRow["BusinessDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `ParseExact` to convert your `yyyyMMdd` string to `DateTime` as follows and then everything is okay.

```
cashRow["BusinessDate"] = DateTime.ParseExact(row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString(), "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the exact format of your input yyyyMMdd (eg: 20181211), just supply it to `DateTime.ParseExact()` and then call  `ToString()` on the returned `DateTime` object.

```
string YourOutput = DateTime.ParseExact(p_dates, "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
cashRow["BusinessDate"] = row.Cells[ClosingDate.Index].Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: what is the change you're suggesting in this?

Comment: You applied the ToString after converting it to DateTime. is cashRow["BusinessDate"] datetime?

Comment: If it is in DateTime why do you need a conversion to DateTime at all?

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime` this will not do the job. because how did it identify that its `dd/MM/yyyy` or `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: The DateTime itself **has no format**. The value is stored internally in a long field

Comment: Edited the answer. Convert.ToDateTime will not work actually. Just the format(dd/MM/yyyy) inside the ToString method will do the job.